# Ошибка в jquery throttle-debounce

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, плагин, callback

При обработке события mousemove в jquery использовал плагин throttle-debounce, а именно функцию debounce для оптимизации цикла внутри. И внутри самого файла throttle-debounce возникает ошибка в callback.apply(). Я не особо шарю в коллбэках и throttle-debonce использую впервые. Что это значит и как это исправить?
[image: Ошибка находится на строчках 146-150 в исходнике throttle-debounce]

Comment: возможно вместо функции вы запустили плагин с каким-то обьектом, нужен код запуска

Comment: @рони, Я использовал вот этот плагин [throttle-debounce](https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce). Вот вся моя функция:
`function editBlockSize(e) {
 id = '#creation_place > ' + '#' + $(this).attr('id');
 sizing = !(sizing);
 x = e.pageX - $(id).offset().left;
 y = e.pageY - $(id).offset().top;
 $(document).on('mousemove', $.debounce(function(e) {
  while (x > parseInt($(id).css('width')) - 5 && sizing === true) {
   x = e.pageX - $(id).offset().left;
   $(id).css('width', x);
  }
 }, 300));
 return false;
}`
После срабатывания debounce появляется ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

укажите задержку  вначале, а потом функцию

jQuery.debounce( **delay**, [ at_begin, ] callback )

```
function editBlockSize(e) {
id = '#creation_place > ' + '#' + $(this).attr('id');
sizing = !(sizing);
x = e.pageX - $(id).offset().left;
y = e.pageY - $(id).offset().top;
$(document).on('mousemove', $.debounce(300,function(e) {  
    while (x > parseInt($(id).css('width')) - 5 && sizing === true) {
        x = e.pageX - $(id).offset().left;
        $(id).css('width', x);
    }
}));
return false;}
```

Comment: Так ошибку не выдает, но страница виснет из-за постоянного выполнения while, будто debounce вообще нет.

Comment: думайте над алгоритом функции, избавьтесь от  while, debounce тут ничем не поможет.